# Issue in locating UI Grid element in Robot Framework + PyCharm + Python

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am having an issue to locate UI Grid element as it's class changing dynamically every time without selecting, after selection and after making it active. I tried by Id also but that also doesn't work as it's generating id every time when we load a page. So can anyone help me out to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Here is code for reference:

Update:
Thanks for the reply, please find below my keywords and variable and also find attached screenshot what I am getting in the result and in UI. The highlighted text box's HTML code is in the attached image, I am able to click in it but when entering values in it getting an error. Refer images UI and Error.

```
Keyword:
click element  ${MANUAL_LINEITEM}
sleep  20s
Set Focus To Element  ${MANUAL_LINENUMBER}
sleep  15s
double click element  ${MANUAL_LINENUMBER}
sleep  5s
input text  ${MANUAL_LINENUMBER}  10

Variables:
${MANUAL_LINENUMBER}  xpath=//div[(@class='height-grid ui-grid-cell-contents 
ng-binding ng-scope invalid ui-grid-cell-focus')]
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track 
by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '- 
cell'" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-01FL height-grid" ng- 
class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" role="gridcell" ui- 
grid-cell="" tabindex="-1" id="1540551802845-7-uiGrid-01FL-cell" aria- 
selected="true"><div class="height-grid ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng- 
scope invalid ui-grid-cell-focus" title="" ng-class=" 
{invalid:grid.validate.isInvalid(row.entity,col.colDef)}" style=""></div> 
</div>
```

[image: UI]
[image: Error]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. In order for you to help you better can you add the code as text to the question and add the robot script for the action you want to execute. Otherwise we need to guess. '

Comment: may be you should look at [how to ask question? MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as your question don't have things like what you have tried, what kind of grid element you have, and giving screenshot will not work in your favor most of the time

Comment: Please don't post code on another site, and more importantly, don't post _pictures_ of code. Please take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the code directly in your question.

Comment: Html you have shared does,'t have the input element referrining. share all the child elemen of the div with ng-repeat

Comment: @Navarasu I have shared all the HTML element what I got from developer tools.